# Sharing gps location in Chrome for android

Tags: android, google-chrome, gps

I've seen this question asked multiple times, so I apologize for asking again. However, the posted solutions are not working.

I'm trying to run web apps that require my position such as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). My laptop browser will ask me permission, and then share my location. My mobile chrome browser just refuses to run the code without saying anything.

I have followed the [official google directions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en). My site settings say that javascript is allowed and location is ask first. All sites respond exactly as if I had blocked location.

Has anyone ran into this issue and been able to fix it?

Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Chrome only accepts requests for location from "secure" sources.

Explained here.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

The issue can fixed by securing your website to use https. Github pages works fine since it is https.